# How to get FieldSet fields in Apex Dynamically (fieldset name is not static)

Tags: apex, fieldsets

```
String fieldSetName = 'Account_FieldSet';
String ObjectName = 'Account';
```

I wanted get list of all fields from this fieldset.

I know if fieldset name is hardcoded in the apex then following syntax works -

```
SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Account_FieldSet.getFields();
```

But here main issue is Object name and fieldset name will come at runtime.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**How to get FieldSet fields in Apex Dynamically (fieldset name is not static)**

Here is the method I came up with lots of trial and errors -

```
public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> readFieldSet(String fieldSetName, String ObjectName)
{
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
    Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(ObjectName);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();

    //system.debug('====>' + DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName));

    Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);

    //List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSetMemberList =  fieldSetObj.getFields();
    //system.debug('fieldSetMemberList ====>' + fieldSetMemberList);  
    return fieldSetObj.getFields(); 
}
```

**You can use result as follows -**

```
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSetMemberList =  Util.readFieldSet('Account_FieldSet','Account');
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : fieldSetMemberList)
{
    system.debug('API Name ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath()); //api name
    system.debug('Label ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel());
    system.debug('Required ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getRequired());
    system.debug('DbRequired ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getDbRequired());
    system.debug('Type ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getType());   //type - STRING,PICKLIST
}
```

Comment: This was marked as community wiki (I just discovered it while looking for a way to do field sets dynamically), not sure if that was intentional but I've removed it because you deserve the rep for it!

Answer (score 7):

There is a slightly shorter way to deal with this. The following method returns null if the field set is undefined, or a list of field set members otherwise:

```
public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFieldSetMembers(String objectTypeName,
        String fieldSetName) {
    DescribeSObjectResult[] describes = Schema.describeSObjects(new String[] {
                objectTypeName
            });

    if (describes != null && describes.size() > 0) {
        // There should only be the one match for the one object type name
        Schema.FieldSet fs = describes[0].fieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);

        return fs.fields;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, @Phil! :-) Thank you for providing a simpler solution!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the code you are looking. Dynamic mapping with field set to clone list of records.

```
// test1 is the filled set on contact

List<Schema.FieldSetMember> schemaset= SObjectType.contact.FieldSets.test1.getFields();

 // clisttoUpdate: fill this list with the records for which you wanted to clone by using dynamic soql with filed set
List<contact> clisttoUpdate=new List<contact>();
//to store mapped records to insert at the end
 List<account> acc=new list<account>();


List<contact> ListWithData=new List<contact>();
List<contact> listForClone=new List<contact>();

for(integer i=0;i<ListWithData.size();i++){

  system.debug(schemaset[i].getFieldPath()+'YYYYYYYYY');
   system.debug(x.get(schemaset[i].getFieldPath())+'FFFFFFFFFFFFF');

   contact cloneRec=new contact();

   for(integer a=0;a<schemaset.size();a++){
          cloneRec.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath()) =clisttoUpdate[i].get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())

   }

   listForClone.add(cloneRec);

}


insert listForClone;
```